# Where to place Logo, left or middle?

Tags: interaction-design, design-patterns, user-expectation, placement, logos

Most people say upper left is the best, due to recognizability issues. I saw a video on  [Treehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/aesthetic-foundations/elements/space-balance-and-unity) and showed that CNN did the bold move, to put it in the middle. Then i checked [CNN](http://edition.cnn.com/) and the logo was on the left, so they updated their bold move.

Any other UX tips for the placement?

Comment: The location of the logo is part of the design as a whole. You can put it on the right if that fits in with the design. Having said that, when in doubt put it on the left.

Answer (score 0):

People read from left to right so I put it on the left. Except when they don't. Then I put it on the right. Except when it stands alone by itself, in which I case I **might** put it in the middle, though sometimes offset in all these cases, but, in all cases, I put it where the designer says to put it.

Answer (score 0):

People expect the logo to be on the left, with other links on the same row just because that's how most sites are.

Centering the logo will work too, if the page's overall layout is centered, and if...

- There's [nothing else in the row](http://duet.me/) with the logo or
- The centered logo is [clearly the focus](http://icelab.com.au/) of that top row, among other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Common use would put it in the top left in most cases - and it's generally a good idea to be consistent with expectations (UX heuristics)

Practicality would keep it out of the centre, as if you align it to one side there is more room for login / common tools / marketing etc

This heat map http://www.nngroup.com/articles/f-shaped-pattern-reading-web-content/ indicates that the content and functionality draws attention, and the logos are ignored, but they are tucked away in the top left in all 3 examples. I wouldn't move it to the middle on these kinds of website incase it distracts attention from the content

Answer (score 0):

You're fine putting it in the centre, as long as there's symmetry.

Take for example [my own website](http://www.saneit.net/), it uses a centre logo mainly because

**1:** The logo is symmetrical **2:** The navigation is **3:** The style allows it.

Most of the time it depends on how complex your navigation is and the complexity of your theme. Minimalism tends to favour centred logos, whereas more 'filled' pages favour blocks of information, rather than split.

I feel that websites that deal with significant portions of text will *almost always* benefit from a left or right aligned logo.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you're going for. In terms of straight usability the logo has to main purposes:

- It tells people which site they're on. Most people hit your site through search engines, so they'll be dropped somewhere on a random page of a random website. This is why the tagline, which explains what your site is, is below the logo.
- It functions as a panic button. If the user gets lost, the click the logo, and return to the homepage.

If you have a complex site, with lots of content, you will need to have these functions. That means you need to logo where people expect it: **top left**.

If, on the other hand your aim is to impress, and to wow people with simplicity, clarity and beauty, you could consider making a home screen with little content: eg a big, beautiful photo, a logo, strapline and three simple menu options. Perhaps one that folds into a more traditional layout as the user progresses.

There's also the case of a primarily centered layout. In this case, having the logo top left would be a jarring exception to your style, and you'll want it centered.

In both cases, you in danger of confusing the user. This means that you need **extra whitespace** and less visual clutter. And you need to test if people recognize that your logo is a logo.

Answer (score 0):

As always, it depends, and to me it would depend on the target audience. Our western culture reads from left to right, eye trackers will also back this up, we start at the top left, and we end our "scan" at the bottom right. Those are the place where you'd put information like logos or other stuff you think is important. In some other countries, people read from right to left, this also affects their scanning pattern (starts at top right, and ends at bottom left). Windows, for example, flips the position of the start button based upon this:
[image]

The start button really counts as the logo there. I know its at the bottom right, and not at the top right, but I think it being at the right in the first place proves my point already. The fact that there is no visual clutter at the top allows people to start from the bottom (and also, since windows is pretty known by know by most users...).

So if you want to ommit the problem, use a centered logo, but I don't see a lot of those being used in many sites, like a previous poster mentioned, use it if the entire site is centered.

Reading material:

http://thenextweb.com/dd/2015/04/15/designing-websites-that-mirror-how-our-eyes-work-part-2/

More proof of what I'm saying:

http://www.aljazeera.net/portal